# How to get the Lie derivative of a differetial form on a submanifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This problem is in Tu's introduction to manifold book, Example 20.11:
Let $\omega$ be the 1 form $-ydx+xdy$and $X$ be tangent vector field $-y\partial/\partial x+x \partial/\partial y$ on unit circle S1.
In this book, Lie derivative $L_X\omega$ is calculated as it is in $R^2$.
The deduction in this book seems to first regard both $\omega$ and $X$ as smooth one form and smooth vector field on the $R^2$, then the Lie derivative of $\omega$ is just anther one form on $R^2$. Then as a regular submanifold, the $L_X\omega$ on unit circle is derived as the restriction of previously obtained one form on $R^2$.

I am wondering, whether this method is true in general, i.e., if we want to calculate the Lie derivative of a smooth form $\omega$ with a smooth vector field $X$ on a regular submanifold $S$, then if we could find a smooth form $\omega_1$ on the embedded Euclidean space $R^n$ with $\omega=i^*\omega_1$,and a smooth vector field $X_1$ on $R^n$ which is indeed tangent to this submanifold (for each $p\in S$, $i_{p,*}(X_p)=X_{1,p}$ where $i$ is the inclusive map), finally can we assert $L_X\omega=i^*L_{X_1}\omega_1$?